# WPF Canvas as a math graphing area

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, math, canvas

In my graphic calculator, I am using canvas as a plane on which graphs of functions are rendered. I have noticed that whenever I input complex functions (I use bezier curves for that, so the more complex the function -> the more points I need to render for the graph to be smooth-looking) it gets quite laggy and overally doesn't perform well.

Which of these solutions are the least computationally costly / thus are the best approach?

**1. (My current solution) Using huge Canvas inside a ScrollViewer that limits the view area**

Cons I have found:

- The whole canvas is rendered, even the non-visible part
- Starts to lag when there is more than 50K elements on the canvas

**2. Using just Canvas that is not so big, and management of panning / zooming through TransformMatrix**

Cons I think there might be (solution not tried):

- Won't it be even more laggy when it will have to redraw and recalculate everything dynammically?

**3. Some other solutions?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at BitmapCache? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this might help with the rendering problem! But still the 'right choice for canvas problem' persists.

Comment: yes, I know, but questions like this are hard to answer, you will need to measure and experiment yourself. I guess a combination of a certain Canvas size combined with BitmapCache could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can avoid it, you really don't want to be using discrete visuals to represent things like charts/graphs; they are very heavy, and are constantly participating in input handling and layout.  I would recommend using WPF's drawing/geometry APIs directly.  I would suggest implementing a custom control which performs its own rendering (see `OnRender`).  I would also suggest implementing `IScrollInfo` so you can manage your own scrolling: you will always know the viewport size and position, which gives you the option of invalidating your geometry when scrolling, and then rebuilding *only* the parts of the graph that are actually in view.  That should reduce the overhead significantly.